# Spring Cloud Config Server - Response Description

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Is there any documentation which provides description of all the elements in Spring Cloud Config Server's response

```
{
   "name":"myapp",
   "profiles":[
      "default"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":null,
   "state":null,
   "propertySources":[
      {
         "name":"vault:myapp",
         "source":{
            "foo":"myappsbar"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"vault:application",
         "source":{
            "baz":"bam",
            "foo":"bar"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on source code it's:

> Simple plain text serializable encapsulation of a list of property sources. Basically a DTO for {@link org.springframework.core.env.Environment}, but also applicable outside the domain of a Spring application.

See: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/environment/Environment.java

and

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/environment/PropertySource.java

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#vault-backend It has a response object which is the same as your question and the documentation can help you understand each and every parameter in that object.